# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined error in reactjs google map

Tags: reactjs

when I trying to include geoocoder api code it shows an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined".

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose, withProps,withHandlers } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker,InfoWindow,GeoCoder } from "react-google-maps"
import { MarkerClusterer } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?AIzaSyAoaDS6fIKlYvEHeTaakCxXqp-UwnggoEgv=3&sensor=true&callback=init",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
   withHandlers({
    onMarkerClustererClick: () => (markerClusterer) => {
      const clickedMarkers = markerClusterer.getMarkers()
      console.log(`Current clicked markers length: ${clickedMarkers.length}`)
      console.log(clickedMarkers)
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) =>{

 return ( <GoogleMap
    zoom={props.maps.zoom}
    center={{ lat:props.maps.lat, lng:props.maps.lng }}
    heading={5}
  >
   <MarkerClusterer
      onClick={props.onMarkerClustererClick}
      averageCenter
      enableRetinaIcons
      gridSize={60}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          key={marker.photo_id}
          position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }}
        />
      ))}
    </MarkerClusterer>
     <Marker
          position={{lat:props.maps.lat, lng:props.maps.lng }}
     >
    <InfoWindow>
        <p>gdgd</p>
      </InfoWindow>
     </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
)});

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ markers: [] })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
        console.log("+mymap++++++++");
        console.log(this.props.myMap);
        this.setState({markers:[{photo_id:1,longitude:76.911270,latitude:11.032595},
                                {photo_id:2,longitude:75.806682,latitude:11.259169},
                                {photo_id:3,longitude:77.213780,latitude:28.617671},
                                {photo_id:4,longitude:78.138991,latitude:9.903245}]})
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyMapComponent markers={this.state.markers} maps={this.props.myMap} />
    )
  }
}
```

In the above code when I trying to create a geocoder variable it shows the error.Here I am trying to get the location name from the latitude and longitude positions of the map using geocoder api.

Comment: <MyMapComponent markers={this.state.markers} maps={this.props.myMap} /> in DemoApp. You probably don't pass myMap prop to DemoApp component.

Comment: when i remove it still showing the same error

Comment: That's not gonna help, `maps` prop will still be undefined if you remove this. You need to pass it to the `MyMapComponent`, since it expects a object with `lat`, `lng` and `zoom` keys.

<MyMapComponent markers={this.state.markers} maps={{ lat: someLatitude, lng: someLongitude, zoom: 6 }} />

Answer (score 1):

You might have included `google` in your `index.html`, so the google variable is not accessible in your component as it is a `window variable`.

Try using `window.google.maps.xxx`, then it must resolve your TypeError

For your particular case

```
import React from 'react';
...

let geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();  // edited


const MyMapComponent = compose(
...
```

Comment: [`react-google-maps`](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/) doesn't even export GeoCoder... Where did you find it? :c

Comment: @Jatimir damn!!! Its all his code, looks like he has all messed up code

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'm sorry, didn't notice he has this imported as well.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code was this fragment:

```
<MyMapComponent markers={this.state.markers} maps={this.props.myMap} />
```

I assume that `DemoApp` was the main application component that you were mounting in the `index.js` file. You haven't passed any props to the `DemoApp component` therefore in `MyMapComponent` a `maps` prop was undefined. Using `props.maps.lat` inside of that component caused the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined` error to appear.

I noticed some other minor issues:

- this code is unnecessary:

  ```
  import { ..., GeoCoder } from 'react-google-maps';
  ```

  `react-google-maps` doesn't even export the component with that name. Maybe it used to, but it no longer does. You can check that in the documentation
- this also isn't required:

  ```
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  ```
- and I changed the googleMapURL to the one from the docs:

  ```
  googleMapURL: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_key_goes_here&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
  ```

  You can skip generating the key for now, but there will be a warning in the console.

Working code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers } from 'recompose';
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps';
import { MarkerClusterer } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer';

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: '400px' }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onMarkerClustererClick: () => (markerClusterer) => {
      const clickedMarkers = markerClusterer.getMarkers();
      console.log(`Current clicked markers length: ${clickedMarkers.length}`);
      console.log(clickedMarkers);
    }
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    zoom={props.maps.zoom}
    center={{ lat: props.maps.lat, lng: props.maps.lng }}
    heading={5}
  >
    <MarkerClusterer
      onClick={props.onMarkerClustererClick}
      averageCenter
      enableRetinaIcons
      gridSize={60}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker key={marker.photo_id} position={{ lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude }} />
      ))}
    </MarkerClusterer>
    <Marker position={{ lat: props.maps.lat, lng: props.maps.lng }}>
      <InfoWindow>
        <p>test text</p>
      </InfoWindow>
    </Marker>
  </GoogleMap>
));

export default class DemoApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const markers = [
      { photo_id: 1, longitude: 76.91127, latitude: 11.032595 },
      { photo_id: 2, longitude: 75.806682, latitude: 11.259169 },
      { photo_id: 3, longitude: 77.21378, latitude: 28.617671 }
    ];

    const myMap = {
      lng: 78.138991,
      lat: 9.903245,
      zoom: 6
    };

    return <MyMapComponent markers={markers} maps={myMap} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: i still need geocoder.when i write `let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()` ,it shows above error

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when were referencing to `window.google.maps.Size` and this line fixed it.

`import { OverlayView } from '@react-google-maps/api'`

Answer (score 0):

You Should need to load `let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` after the loading Map. Put a if conditioning check map is load or not